# How to align and snap path to path in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, alignment, snapping

I'm looking for a solution for this. I need help aligning/snapping a shape to a corner in Illustrator CC. What I really want to do is place a path on top of another, EXACTLY on top. Here's a picture of the scenario:

[image: Screenshot example]

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): [Snap paths in Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73579/52050). Basically you can't snap paths, only points or the bounding box. So you either need to strategically place anchor points or snap to the bounding box and rotate later (or use a plugin as in your answer).

Answer (score 3):

I've finally found a way to do this with a plug-in called "SubScribe". It's an awesome plugin that you can download for free, by Astute Graphics. Here's the link: http://astutegraphics.com/software/subscribe/

Here's a quick tutorial:

1) Click and hold "Circle by 2 or 3 points" and select "Tanget Circle":

[image]

2) Click on a path and then click on the other path across it:

[image]

3) Choose the radius of the circle you want to create. It'll automatically snap to the corner.

[image]

4) Voi là! You have a circle perfectly snapped to a corner. DONE.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using smart paths and then adjusting with keyboard in outline mode zoomed in. Not an easy exact way but doable.

Comment: I don't think it will be an exact alignment if you do it like this.